# Not understanding LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I am maintaining a project and have come across some code which I can't understand. LINQ query:

```
var toDraw = from tile in testArr.AsEnumerable()
             where tile.Item_Business_Unit != null ? 
             ((tile.Ending_Date >= DateTime.Now || tile.Ending_Date == DateTime.MinValue) && 
             ((tile.Sales_Code == null) || (tile.Sales_Code.ToString() == customerNumber) || 
             (tile.Sales_Code.ToString() == cpg)) && (tile.Unit_Price != 0)) : 
             ((tile.Ending_Date >= DateTime.Now || tile.Ending_Date == DateTime.MinValue) && 
             ((tile.Sales_Code == null) || (tile.Sales_Code.ToString() == customerNumber) || 
             (tile.Sales_Code.ToString() == cpg)) && (tile.Unit_Price != 0))
                             select tile;
```

From what I understand, from an array a tile is being selected which has the following criteria:

- Ending date can be `datetime.now` or `datetime.minvalue`
- Sales code can be null or can be equal to customer no or cpg
- Unit price should be greater than 0

But I am not understanding why there is a conditional expression after `tile.Item_Business_Unit` since both of the conditions perform the same thing. So will the item be selected even if it has a null business unit? And does this work different from normal if/else operations?

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a relic. At some point, `tile.Item_Business_Unit` was used in the query, but it isn't anymore - the ternary just remained since the guy who made the change didn't bother removing it.

Comment: @Luaan thanks. so it means both perform the same thing. Just wanted confirmation because it is a project critical to the business and I cant mess with it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you want to be absolutely sure, have a look at the code for `Item_Business_Unit` - it's possible it has a side-effect you could be removing. It would be rather sneaky (and is the kind of offence you'd kill the other guy for :P), but it's possible. If it has no side-effects, you can remove it safely.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Luaan and sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you being thrown by the shortcut notation?

```
x = (test_case) ? (true_part) : (false_part);
```

If `test_case` evaluates to **true**, you would have

[image: true_part]

Whereas if `test_case` evaluates to **false**, this expression would be evaluated

[image: false_part]

**UPDATE:**

As an FYI: The resulting test of both sides of that conditional expression above are equal, so that cryptic code is not even necessary.

You could replace that with this:

```
var toDraw = from tile in testArr.AsEnumerable()
    where 
    ((tile.Ending_Date >= DateTime.Now || tile.Ending_Date == DateTime.MinValue) &&
    ((tile.Sales_Code == null) || (tile.Sales_Code.ToString() == customerNumber) || (tile.Sales_Code.ToString() == cpg)) &&
    (tile.Unit_Price != 0)) 
    select tile;
```

Comment: Right, so its the same thing. Sorry for bothering the community with a stupid question. Was just confirming.

Comment: I ask a lot of stupid questions on here. Sometimes, you just don't know.

Comment: I keep looking at the two sides to that conditional expression in the screenshots. They look identical. Did you add a typo to the original? If not, you might be able to remove that cryptic test. It would make the query more readable to all other software developers.

Comment: No. It's not a typo. I found this code in a project I am maintaining and was scratching my head looking at the left part and then the right part again and again just like you and was not understanding why he'd use similar conditions. Then I just got frustrated and asked to have a third opinion on this. :D

Comment: Well, I hate to say it, but leave it as is. Others in the group (I've learned) get really upset when you change code that has been working for years. You might be able to put a comment in there saying how you think it should be written.